# Pabot - Parallel run exception

Tags: azure-pipelines, robotframework

I am getting the following error while running the below pabot command from Azure devops pipeline. If I run the same in my local VM (Where pipeline also runs), no issues are faced.

Could someone have any thought on the point of failures?

```
C:\foo\boo\pabot --pabotlib --processes 1 --testlevelsplit  --i tagName  C:/foo/boo
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\program files\python38\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
     return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,File "c:\program files\python38\lib\runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
     exec(code, run_globals)
File "c:\program files\python38\lib\site-packages\pabot\pabotlib.py", line 547, in <module>
    RobotRemoteServer(
     File "c:\program files\python38\lib\site-packages\pabot\robotremoteserver.py", line 92, in __init__
self.serve()
File "c:\program files\python38\lib\site-packages\pabot\robotremoteserver.py", line 144, in serve
self._server.activate()
File "c:\program files\python38\lib\site-packages\pabot\robotremoteserver.py", line 220, in activate
self.server_bind()
File "c:\program files\python38\lib\socketserver.py", line 466, in server_bind
    self.socket.bind(self.server_address)
OSError: [WinError 10013] An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions
[ERROR] EXCEPTION RAISED DURING PABOT EXECUTION
[ERROR] PLEASE CONSIDER REPORTING THIS ISSUE TO https://github.com/mkorpela/pabot/issues
Stopping PabotLib process
Could not connect to PabotLib - assuming stopped already
Total testing: 0.0 seconds
Elapsed time:  5 minutes 31.75 seconds
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\program files\python38\Scripts\pabot-script.py", line 11, in <module>
     load_entry_point('robotframework-pabot==1.10.1', 'console_scripts', 'pabot')()
   File "c:\program files\python38\lib\site-packages\pabot\pabot.py", line 1761, in main
    _initialize_queue_index()
  File "c:\program files\python38\lib\site-packages\pabot\pabot.py", line 1700, in _initialize_queue_index
   raise RuntimeError("Can not connect to PabotLib at %s" % _PABOTLIBURI)
```

Comment: "An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions" Seems like you lack permissions where your pipeline runs and you have those permissions in your VM.

Comment: Hi there, are you still troubled by this question? If so, could you please provide a sample of your pipeline so that people can investigate the question further?